# DHT22 Sensor AttributeError: module 'adafruit_dht' has no attribute 'read_retry'

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, sensors, raspberry-pi4

recently I have been trying to get the DHT22 temperature and humidity sensor to work for my school project using python(thonny) on a Raspberry Pi 4. I managed to find this code online that appears to make sense, however I have been constantly getting the error "AttributeError: module 'adafruit_dht' has no attribute 'read_retry'". I have installed all the relevant modules and google didn't yield any solutions that work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
import sys
import argparse
import time

# This imports the Adafruit DHT software installed via pip
import adafruit_dht 


# Initialize the DHT22 sensor
SENSOR = adafruit_dht.DHT22

# GPIO4 on the Raspberry Pi
SENSOR_PIN = 4
print(adafruit_dht.read_retry(adafruit_dht.DHT22, 27))

def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-f", "--fahrenheit", help="output temperature in Fahrenheit", action="store_true")

    return parser.parse_args()

def celsius_to_fahrenheit(degrees_celsius):
        return (degrees_celsius * 9/5) + 32

def main():
    args = parse_args()

    while True:
        try:
            # Gather the humidity and temperature
            # data from the sensor; GPIO Pin 4
            humidity, temperature = dht.read_retry(SENSOR, SENSOR_PIN)

        except RuntimeError as e:
            # GPIO access may require sudo permissions
            # Other RuntimeError exceptions may occur, but
            # are common.  Just try again.
            print(f"RuntimeError: {e}")
            print("GPIO Access may need sudo permissions.")

            time.sleep(2.0)
            continue

        if args.fahrenheit:
            print("Temp: {0:0.1f}*F, Humidity: {1:0.1f}%".format(celsius_to_fahrenheit(temperature), humidity))
        else:
            print("Temp:{0:0.1f}*C, Humidity: {1:0.1f}%".format(temperature, humidity))

        time.sleep(2.0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: The latest example docs import the code as `Adafruit_DHT` so the case may be important? Though the whole project is deprecated and recommends other libraries be used: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_DHT/blob/master/examples/simpletest.py

Comment: I initially tried to import Adafruit_DHT in the code but I would just keep getting the error "cannot import name 'Beaglebone_Black_Driver' from 'Adafruit_DHT' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/Adafruit_DHT/__init__.py)". I was told to instead import adafruit_dht as the Adafruit_DHT was out of the date which lead to the error I mentioned about above.